# Auto Resizing the height and the width of a web application

Tags: css, aspect-ratio, jsfiddle

I'm developing a web app and i want to auto resize three columns divs filled with a background image in order to make them fill the whole page whenever i zoom in or out with ctrl- and + exactly like [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net), here is what i have written to make this effect but it failed:

HTML:

```
<div id="three_columns_container">
     <div id="first-column">...</div>
     <div id="second-column">...</div>
     <div id="third-column">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first-column{
    background:('slice.png');
    width: 15%;
    height: 97%;
}
#second-column{
    background:('slice.png');
    width: 15%;
    height: 97%;
}
#third-column{
    background:('slice.png');
    width: 70%;
    height: 97%;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
      $("#three_columns_container").height() = $(window).height * 0.97;
      $("#three_columns_container").width() = $(window).width* 0.97;
    });
```

this link may help solving the problem but it doesn't make the exact effect
[link](http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/index.htm)

i was wondering if anybody can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is solution for your problem:

**CSS**

```
#firstColumn {
    width: 15%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #1e3340;
    float: left;
}
#secondColumn {
    width: 70%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #305a5e;
    float: left;    
}
#thirdColumn {
    width: 15%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #323e45;
    float: left;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="three_columns_container">
     <div id="firstColumn">...</div>
     <div id="secondColumn">...</div>
     <div id="thirdColumn">...</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divRatio = {};
    setRatio('firstColumn');
    setRatio('secondColumn');
    setRatio('thirdColumn');
    $(window).resize(function () {
        fixHeight('firstColumn');
        fixHeight('secondColumn');
        fixHeight('thirdColumn');
    });
    function setRatio(container) {
        var selector = '#' + container;
        divRatio[container] = $(selector).height() / $(selector).width();
    }
    function fixHeight(container) {
        var selector = '#' + container,
            ratio = divRatio[container],
            height = ratio * $(selector).width();
        $(selector).height(height);     
    }
});
```

Comment: That's Really a great answer it works very efficient, thanks a lot, but i have a small question, what if i want to put in the background an image url instead of the bg color? i tried it but it doesn't fill the whole height of the div, do you know how?

Comment: I worked in solution for fixing the background but it's not very stable [there are also differences in the different browsers for detecting the background size (there's also problem if you haven't specified the 'background-size' property)]. The upper script also will not work if the page is zoomed when it's loaded so it's working just when you open the web page with 100% zoom. May be better approach is detecting the zoom level...but just see what a mess is that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

Comment: This just helps in getting the zoom level but actually i tried to look in the codes in order to be able to  set the zoom level but i think that this is not possible, do you have any idea how to make this?
also i found this plugin i think it will help alot but not with the maximum zoom in: http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html

Comment: You can not set the zoom level. You can just check it and set specific size of specific elements which size depend on this zoom level.

Comment: There is a strange thing happens in your script when i need to make the columns start from the top by a margin of 100px for example, the script is ineffective then :s

Comment: You have to compute the ratio for the margin too. It's similar to the script I've wrote but instead of height use the margin.

Answer (score 0):

for variable width use %age. and for fixed use pixels. what else dont you understand. if you require the background pic also to be resizd you will have to write js for that.